# Which acid to choose when designing a world with acid seas?

Tags: acid-base, chemistry-in-fiction

I'm currently writing a narrative and hoping to include a world which is home to a sea of some form of 'nasty' substance (doesn't have to be acid).

The varieties of inhabitants of this world have evolved mostly on the lands and eventually built their cities right up to the shorelines of this acidic sea. (In some cases I may even have cities that float and migrate across it).

I'm imagining some kind of scientific or industrial endeavor they perform whereby they've created ships that can withstand the chemicals (at least in short term) by lining their hulls with a type of [ablative shielding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ablative_armor).

Also desirable (although not essential) would be for the composition to not be immediately fatal. A carbon life form (or would they likely be silicate?) could fall in and maybe swim for a few minutes and leave with only some semi minor chemical burns. Yet prolonged exposure would most definitely be fatal.

I'm also wondering if the inhabitants could harness this chemical in some imaginative way such as for propulsion or agricultural/industrial means?

My question is, what kind of chemical/cocktail could I use to fit these kinds of parameters?

Comment: As any "rocky planet" is made of metal oxides, Fe oxides, Si oxides, Ca oxides that would counter any real acidic ocean, "best" you can hope for are organic acids from an abundance of carbon that has not yet met the abundance of (bound) oxygen. So if this should be a "hard fiction" you will have to make due with $\ce{H2CO3}$ and acetic acid. Or, you need some special polt to explain it.

Comment: Hi and welcome to chemistry.stackexchange.com. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. Your question may be a bit broad, but that’ll be up to the community to decide. As for the usage part: Most certainly, all acids that the chemical industry produces are useful for *something* (and most of the time, one just uses sulphuric acid because it is the cheapest).

Comment: @GyroGearloose thanks, that's helpful. What if the size of the body was reduced to that of a lake? These certainly occur at least here on Earth: https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=acidic%20lake

Comment: Local conditions could be **very, very** different. Decaying pyrite can release sulfuric acid. (I'm now only a hobbyist on chemistry, so I can't be really sure.) Search the internet for ecological disasters with mining Fe, and be sure to verify (there's a lot of myths out there lacking any science).

Comment: Get realistic. [Venerean clouds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venus#Atmosphere_and_climate) are made of sulfuric acid, they say.

Comment: @IvanNeretin yes, but there is no ocean. Sulfuric acid aggressively binds any water, so terraforming Venus  by cooling its atmosphere down and adding lost hydrogen from outside would certainly result in highly acidic oceans, at first. Until the temperature has decreased to a human-bearable temperature. Then, the acid would dissolve the soil and (mostly) neutralize.

Comment: That's quite possible. Now what if we imagine a world which is mostly like Venus, but has less metals (say, not enough to neutralize all that acid)?

Comment: If your story can accommodate a basic ocean or sea, I can suggest a really good one.

Comment: Basic is easy to get: water+ammonia. This has been explored [before](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Light).

Comment: Sure @ShankRam. What are you thinking?

Comment: exactly what at @IvanNeretin told. Water + ammonia fits in beautifully. At high conc. it is corrosive, it can be used to make fertilizers, prolonged exposure causes burning sensations and so on...

Answer (score 2):

Coca Cola or a mixture of Coca Cola and Pepsi Cola would probably be a good choice.

It's not immediately fatal for carbon life forms that fall into it. Only prolonged exposure will cause digestion and damage to bones and teeth.

Due to the phosphoric acid ships with iron hulls would withstand corrosion due to passivation through the formation of iron phosphate (also a molluscicide to protect from shipworms).

In agriculture phosphate is also a potent fertilizer.

For propulsion purposes, Cola together with Mentos is a well-known hybrid rocket propellant.

Comment: Great answer. I'm now wondering how I could account for the occurrence of phosphate and how to keep the acid concentration up through some kind of phosphorous cycle? (phosphorous rocks/rain?)

Comment: I think that it is really hard to consistently model a habitable world with acidic oceans since acids would tend to be neutralized by many minerals in such a world. Phosphoric acid could be formed by hypothetic vulcanic exhalations of P4O10 (fumaroles, hot springs, or, under the sea, black smokers). However, afaik this does not occur on earth. Here you rather have CO2 or SO2. The latter forms sulphuric acid which is more aggressive than H3PO4.